# Formulating Transformation Matrix?

Tags: matrices

How to formulate a transformation matrix for the following operation? Like all the examples I found are different and I can't understand how to solve this problem:

y=A.X

y = (y1 y2)'

x = (x1 'x2)

(y1 y2)' = (x1 x2)'

(-x1, x2)' = (-x1, -x2)'

Comment: I'm having a hard time following exactly what your transformation is. But in general, the jth column of the transformation matrix for a transformation $T$ is $T(\mathbf{e_j})$. So the first thing you need to do is apply the transformation to each of the $e_j$'s. After that you're effectively done.

Answer (score 0):

For X gives the vector $(1,0)$ (as column)  calculate corresponding $t$ vector using the given formula. That would be the first column of $A$. Now repeat the same with $X=(0,1)$ to get the second column of $A$.